# Django - How to redirect to a different view without returning a redirect HTTP response? (e.g. .NET's Server.Transfer)

Tags: asp.net, django, redirect

I'm working on an application where in a certain circumstance a redirect must take place, but the necessary querystring parameters are extremely large and at risk of not working in certain browsers / HTTP proxies.

In the past when working with .NET, I could do a `Server.Transfer` to perform a redirect without sending anything to the client.

Is there a similar capability or pattern I can use in Django to accomplish this?  Some things I've considered are:

- Transferring the parameters out of the querystring and into Session (or other server-side) state, and doing a normal 302 redirect
- Having the first view function directly call the second view function

Neither of these approaches feels right; what other possibilities should I consider?

Comment: totaly agree with your two options, but the second one is quite wrong. I would go for the first one and use Django messages. It's really usefull for this kind of features. Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: In our project we have a part where we use your second approach - a view function just call one of 3 other views depending on some conditions. As for me - both solutions look OK